# Change the order of files grabbed by a Wildcard

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wildcard

I'm attempting to compile all the files in a directory into a single file (coffeescript, if it matters). I'm using the wildcard (*) to grab all the files in a folder, but I would like to organize them by modification date rather than alphabetically. In other words, I'd like to use the wildcard, but the order matters.

Is there a way to change the order files are grabbed in when using the wildcard to specify files?

Comment: You can use `dir /b /o:d` or `dir /b /o:-d` to list the files ordered by date/time and make a file list in a file or a variable, but it'd be nice if you add the actual code in the question to make it possible to provide a ready-to-use answer. Also I suppose there might be a duplicate question.

Comment: I was hoping someone would find a dupe, because I looked for awhile and couldn't find one. Using dir as a variable would probably work.

Answer (score 1):

To build a list of files ordered by date/time in a variable use `dir` and `for /f` parse-loop:

```c
@echo off
for /f "eol=* delims=" %%a in ('dir "." /b /o:d') do call set files=%%files%% "%%a"
echo %files%
some-build-app --output release/scripts.js %files%
pause
```

To reverse the order change `/o:d` to `/o:-d`.